How did "Gauss's law" get its name?
Did Carl Friedrich Gauss derive Gauss's law? How did the Maxwell equation we call "Gauss's law" become known as that? In class, we went over how you derive it from Coulomb's law, but I don't see why it became known as "Gauss's law."

It is not specific to Maxwell's equations and electricity, it holds for any inverse square force law. "The law was first formulated by Joseph-Louis Lagrange in 1773, followed by Carl Friedrich Gauss in 1835, both in the context of the attraction of ellipsoids." Gauss's law. Gauss's work is Theoria attractionis corporum sphaeroidicorum ellipticorum homogeneorum, methodo nova tractata.

It is tied to the history of Gauss' theorem.
